# How to dynamically change function's return type that depends on earlier code?

Tags: typescript

Let me explain: you have a class Player. In Player, you have two getters: `isPlaying: boolean` & `current: AudioResource | undefined`. What I want to do is to make `current` return type 100% `AudioResource`, without undefined if `isPlaying` is 100% true. I saw it in some projects but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Then return `AudioResource` only, for example `return data as AudioResource` without seeing any code, we don't know what you know and don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [user-defined type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to determine (at runtime) whether the player is active and has the audio resource or not. Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEE0HsFdQEwJZwHYHIAuoDOALSB3UdHBLIgTwAcBTAGm0lB2oCdrUyBDZUagD04BbSgBtqALgBQ6KtVABBaIkgAlalhgsAxnIC8oAN6TQoNpzicARmPGg15q2IDK6M4IDckgL6fJIUAAqzKAABgAKIpzkrCGgWpFYZOQw8OpaLAiW1HBScNTxnGxxCWQRUayGxqAA5tSYWtAsbMiYABQAlLaKymoajTqgAD6g0Mh5AGYIyNmeJrWYpGXkU9WgHbaWkJBi3J5ekgf+AbI10IVwWFLSJ0us8lroCABuepUmDU3ULV1KCKrqmh0s1Ai0iy2Q1Vsrmg1D2vnGowefx4pHujxea1E5RYtluLE6oCx0RYINKYLuSIxRhMbHQjR4RNYADpQVEVnsDjIaKA8QBJZCcSmvalxRrNdC2UYTKYzKqs8GQ0DjTgiLCw7zwxGPSAorD8wXouStRk4nnk-G2E2ks3Y-VCt6mOr00AAQhNLKwS3Z3gOfjAAFUsJxarwBMIbActDqsJgrfppoQ8R1fO6PuLgSZQCAAHoAfkk7vl3szJhz+ckCHGa1RQuN5va7QdqbFX3QGZLZaqhc9YOLJdLwDzPorVdapDthrr2IbTfNTLTrfbmc7Jm7XohS4HQ-2QA)

```ts
// You didn't show this type, so here's an example:
type AudioResource = {
  readable: ReadableStream;
};

// The `Player` class you described:
declare class Player {
  get current (): AudioResource | undefined;
  get isPlaying (): boolean;
}


// Type guards:

type PlayerActive = {
  current: AudioResource;
  isPlaying: true;
};

function isActive (player: Player): player is PlayerActive {
  return player.isPlaying;
}

type PlayerInactive = {
  current: undefined;
  isPlaying: false;
};

function isInactive (player: Player): player is PlayerInactive {
  return !player.isPlaying;
}


// Usage example:

const player = new Player();

player.current;
     //^? (property) Player.current: AudioResource | undefined
player.isPlaying;
     //^? (property) Player.isPlaying: boolean

if (isActive(player)) {
  player.current;
       //^? (property) current: AudioResource
  player.isPlaying;
       //^? (property) isPlaying: true
}

if (isInactive(player)) {
  player.current;
       //^? (property) current: undefined
  player.isPlaying;
       //^? (property) isPlaying: false
}
```